Is there a button for merging branches in GitLens for VS Code?
I am editing a repository in VS Code (v1.89.1) on Windows 11, using the GitLens extension (v15.0.4)
Currently the git repository in question is purely local and not published anywhere.
I want to merge another committed branch into the existing "main" branch.
So as most other features of GitLens also have GUI buttons, I am wondering where to find the button for merging.
Merging branches via the Command Palette (CTRL+Shift+P) and the Command "GetLens: Git Merge..." works just fine.
As I am new to using git in general and also just taking my first steps in GitLens maybe I am just missing something here.
This is what my "branches" section in the GUI looks like:
buttons for switch, compare and favorite are present
Thanks in advance
